# Animate before page change not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I'm trying to make an animation occur before the page change. I've copied the jquery from another thread on this site and edited it to fit my html. This same code works in a fiddle but not in my page. I'd be grateful for the help!

The page changes without any of the script taking place

EDIT: It seems when I change #link in the jquery to html it works fine. However no other element works. Weird.

Jquery:

```
$("#link").click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
$(this).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
}, 5000, function() {
    document.location.href = this.href;
});
});
```

Html:

```
<a id="link" href="/page/"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#link").click(function(e) {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 0.25,
    }, 5000, function() {
      document.location.href = this.href;
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work either. The page changes instantly, like the script isn't there. The other parts of that file work correctly though.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `document.location.href = this.href;`, try using this:

`window.location = this.href;`